# image scale proportionally within specified column bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get image fit with bootstrap column in a row proportionally within specified height 300px,   i have tried so many ways but unfortunately its not fit with column width (my 1st image dimension is 262*380 and 2nd image dimension 546*380 and im using img-responsive class)

I need my image should be like this [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLqG.png)

but im getting like this [Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzNSs.png)

My HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="grid">
        <img src="https://static5.thumbtackstatic.com/_assets/images/release/pages/jobs/submodules/gallery/images/lunch-5502ae26.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="grid">
        <img src="https://static7.thumbtackstatic.com/_assets/images/release/pages/jobs/submodules/gallery/images/lounge-0cd3d802.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS

```
.grid {
  height: 300px;
  border-right: 4px;
}

.grid img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-cover grid" style="background-image: url(https://static5.thumbtackstatic.com/_assets/images/release/pages/jobs/submodules/gallery/images/lunch-5502ae26.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 bg-cover grid" style="background-image: url(https://static7.thumbtackstatic.com/_assets/images/release/pages/jobs/submodules/gallery/images/lounge-0cd3d802.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.grid {
  height: 300px;
}

.grid img {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg-cover {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px
}
```

Comment: Make sure the columns `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` have some height set to them. I was doing that via the `grid` class.

Comment: Thank you for you answers bro its working, cant we get same results using img instead of background-image?

Comment: Images usually have different dimensions and it is hard to make them fit the right dimension of box, as the box would change as per window/viewport width (being a bootstrap grid). Thanks to `background-size: cover` which always comes handy. Trust me, this is a very popular and effective method.